# Can you recommend some softwares for Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: software-recommendation

I would like to install some softwares to my newly installed Ubuntu. I want softwares dealing with electronics, physics and such like subjects. (like a scientific educational and experimental one).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you edit your question to include more detailed information about what tasks you want to perform, this will make it easier for us to give you advice. Right now, [Frantique](http://askubuntu.com/users/68484/frantique)'s [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/150397/22949) is as specific as can reasonably be given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Electrical | Linux App Finder](http://linuxappfinder.com/scientificandengineering/electrical)
- [Debian Science Electronics packages](http://blends.alioth.debian.org/science/tasks/electronics)
- [DebianScience Engineering](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianScience/Engineering)
- [DebianScience Physics](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianScience/Physics)
- kicad, pcb, geda  - Printed circuit boards
- scilab - "... Scilab includes hundreds of mathematical functions. It has a high level programming language allowing access to advanced data structures, 2-D and 3-D graphical functions. A large number of functionalities is included in Scilab: control, simulation, optimization, signal processing... Xcos, the hybrid dynamic systems modeler and simulator is provided with the platform."
- KmPlot - is a mathematical function plotter for the KDE-Desktop.
- Kig - is free and open source interactive geometry software

open synaptic and search for `AVR` or `Atmel` or `Microchip`

also `Google` is your friend

Answer (score 4):

1. Open `Software Center`.
2. Choose `Science & Engineering`.
3. Take a look to the offer.

Comment: I viewed it but I can't make my choice.

Comment: Well, read the descriptions, and see which one meets your needs. What is interesting for me, can differ from what you like. :)